# Call to undefined method Yoeunes\Toastr\Toastr::message() (View: /home/_ke_nzy_/house/resources/views/payment-view.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, dart

> This is where Toastr is being called on my payment.view.blad.php file

```
<script src="{{asset('assets/admin')}}/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/admin')}}/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/admin')}}/js/theme.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/admin')}}/js/sweet_alert.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/admin')}}/js/toastr.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/admin')}}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{!! Toastr::message() !!}
```

The error sends me to a Facade.php under vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:261

```
public static function setFacadeApplication($app)
    {
        static::$app = $app;
    }

    /**
     * Handle dynamic, static calls to the object.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $args
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

        if (! $instance) {
            throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
        }


        return $instance->$method(...$args);
    }
}
```

> the error is pointing to
>
> ```
> return $instance->$method(...$args);
> ```

If more details is needed, I will provide

I've tried commenting out the error to no avail

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question a bit more. Try adding some information pointing the usage of Toastr.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where in the documentation did you see a method named `message` being called? that class does not have a method named `message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the `yoeunes/toastr` Laravel package.

There is no `message()` method in the `Toastr`, this is why you get this error.

Just remove the `{!! Toastr::message() !!}` from your blade views, as the `toastr` scripts will be added automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some where in your files you added a `message()` method/function which is not recognized in Laravel.

Best if you put out more of your code to see where the error is originating from.